# Friend Operator << overloading issues,

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, private, friend

I'm having an issue with my `operator<<` overloading where I can not access the private variables of the class it is in no matter what I do because it will say that the variables are private as a compiler error. This is my current code:

```
#include "library.h"
#include "Book.h"

using namespace cs52;

Library::Library(){
   myNumberOfBooksSeenSoFar=0;
}
//skipping most of the functions here for space

Library operator << ( ostream &out, const Library & l ){
   int i=myNumberOfBooksSeenSoFar;
   while(i<=0)
   {
      cout<< "Book ";
      cout<<i;
      cout<< "in library is:";
      cout<< l.myBooks[i].getTitle();
      cout<< ", ";
      cout<< l.myBooks[i].getAuthor();
   }


   return (out);
}
```

And the function prototype and private variables in `library.h` are

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H
#define LIBRARY_H
#define BookNotFound 1
#include "Book.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

namespace cs52{

   class Library{
   public:
      Library();
      void newBook( string title, string author );
      void checkout( string title, string author ) {throw (BookNotFound);}
      void returnBook( string title, string author ) {throw (BookNotFound);}
      friend Library operator << ( Library& out, const Library & l );

   private:

      Book myBooks[ 20 ];
      int myNumberOfBooksSeenSoFar;

   };
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `<<` operator should have this protoype:

```
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream &out, const Library & l )
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to return a reference to `std::ostream` object so that you can chain stream operations.

Also, If you declare it as friend in your `Library` class you should be able to access all the members(private/protected) of the `Library` class in your overloaded function.

---

As such i fail to understand your code, You declared your `<<` operator as:

```
friend Library operator << ( Library& out, const Library & l );
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You defined your operator function with prototype:

```
Library operator << ( ostream &out, const Library & l )
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

They are different!
In short you never declared the function where you are accessing the private member as a friend of your class and Hence the error. 
Also, the return type is Incorrect as I mentioned before.

Comment: I know I should, that's why I'm confused because it's still saying that myNum... is private upon compile. Here is the error code if that helps.

C:\Users\Devin\Documents\C++ SMCCLASS\LibrarySystem\library.h||In function 'cs52::Library operator<<(std::ostream&, const cs52::Library&)':|
C:\Users\Devin\Documents\C++ SMCCLASS\LibrarySystem\library.h|23|error: 'int cs52::Library::myNumberOfBooksSeenSoFar' is private|

Comment: @Devin: Are you sure? Your function prototype is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: @Devin: Check the updated answer, I think that is your problem. Pay attention to the parameter types!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The code from the question won't even compile because the types are all wrong.